# convert MySQL BLOB to .sql file with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hope I ask this correctly. I need to generate a .sql file for a table in my DB. But it also contains a BLOB type. Now when I generate a .sql file from within phpMyAdmin, the BLOB looks like this:

> 0xffd8ffe000104a46494600010101006000600000ffdb004300080606070605080707070....

But when I generate on from PHP the data looks like this:
[image]

So then when I try to upload my PHP generated .sql file, its gives me errors. How can I generate a .sql file with the correct BLOB data?

Below is my code:

```
$message .= "
--
-- Table structure for table `upload`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `upload` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `document_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `size` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `content` mediumblob NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=0 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `upload`
--

";

            $upload = DBC::dbsql("SELECT * FROM upload;");
            while($getUpload = DBC::dbfetch($upload))
            {
                $upload_id = $getUpload['id'];
                $uid = $getUpload['uid'];
                $document_name = $getUpload['document_name'];
                $name = $getUpload['name'];
                $type = $getUpload['type'];
                $size = $getUpload['size'];
                $content = $getUpload['content'];

                $message .= "INSERT INTO `upload` (`id`, `uid`, `document_name`, `name`, `type`, `size`, `content`) VALUES
('$upload_id', '$uid', '$document_name', '$name', '$type', '$size', '$content')";
            }

            $sql_name = "college.sql";
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');   
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
            header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$sql_name."\"");
            print $message;
```

Comment: Show your **code** as well as the ouput. We cant help you understand what is going on if we can't see what its doing.

Comment: Code added as requested